# Ways to attach a shuttle to the ground

Tags: star-trek

I am rewatching ST:ENT and on S3E6 around minute 31, the shuttle gets blown off the Sphere by a malfunctioning thruster. After they shot the thruster, the shuttle crashes down to the Sphere again. Therefore, the shuttle was only attached to the ground (i.e. Sphere) by gravity.

It made me wondering: are there ways to attach a shuttle to the ground, e.g. if there is low gravity or turbulences have to be expected? E.g., do the shuttles have a magnetic lock to pin them to metal objects? Some kind of hook to attach them to, e.g., an asteroid?

If so, in which series did the shuttles have what means to attach the shuttle to the ground?

Specifically:

- Ways to attach the shuttle in the ST:ENT era?
- Ways to attach the shuttle in the ST:TOS era?
- Ways to attach the shuttle in the ST:TNG, ST:VOY and ST:DS9 era? Did the Delta-Flyer have any special means to attach it?
- Have there been other ways described in EU to attach the Shuttle to the ground?

Comment: Take off their hats! Wait, no, that's Popes in a Volkswagen...

Answer (score 1):

ST:ENT: Ways to attach a shuttle that don't require very advanced technology: Suction cups, magnets, spikes, ropes, using a thruster to keep the shuttle down.

ST:TOS and later: Tractor beams. If you can pull something towards yourself, you can also pull yourself towards something. For all I know, ST shuttles used tractor beams for landing. The image below from *Beyond the Barrier* has no visible exhaust, but dust is pushed off the ground by *something*.

[image]

Comment: Do you have any canon support for any of this? Any examples? FYI, a picture from a fan work does not support your position.

Comment: I did not know that was fan art. I googled "Star Trek shuttle landing", and that was all I found. Also, the OP asked for "ways to attach a shuttle to the ground", which I answered. And a tractor beam IS canon, though I don't have any evidence as to whether or not shuttles were equipped with one (though it would make sense that they were).

Comment: The question is what did they *actually* have, not what could they have *plausibly* had. And it's not just the picture that's fan art, *Beyond the Barrier* is a fan recut of *Star Trek V: The Final Frontier*.

Comment: I think it was mentioned in a few novels that a "tractor field", presumably something ground-side, was used at landing pads. Can't find specific references right now.

Answer (score 1):

As there are no "canonical" shuttle "docking clamps" to the ground in any of the series I can think of (other than maybe DS9), I assume you are asking for HYPOTHETICAL anchor/docking mechanism that would be consistent with the tech level.

At ENT level, I'd expect them to fire 3-4 rocket-propelled anchors into the ground and winch them tight.

At TOS level, one wonders if the shuttle has a small tractor beam. If it does, and there is power, it may be able to hold the ground with the tractor beam.

At TNG or higher level, tractor beam on a shuttle is probably given, and a proper landing site may have "tractor fields" which is presumably some sort of landing site equipment designed to push/pull a shuttle to soft landing and takeoff. If there is no field, perhaps shuttle's deflectors can be configured to provide an "angled surface" so the gusts actually pushes down on the craft rather than throwing it off.

Comment: No, I am looking for canonical ways to fixate a shuttle, displayed in the series or comic or described in a book. EU is also accepted.